# Is there a specific mathematical term for a shape whose dimensions are defined?

Tags: geometry, definition

When I say the word "circle", I know that I have described a "shape". Specifically, a "circle" is the shape formed by the set of all points in a plane that are at a given distance from a given point. I don't need to provide any more information about the circle in order for it to qualify as a shape.

However, if I describe more specifically, a "circle with a radius of 5 meters", I do not quite know what I am describing, in terms of a generic mathematical definition. Now that I've added the dimension of the circle to my description, what is it called? Is there an official word or phrase for this, other than "shape plus dimensions"?

Comment: 'Manifolds' are a subset of all such spaces.

Comment: No. What you can say is that you are describing a *specific* (or *particular*) circle instead of a *generic* circle. Also, note that the term *shape* itself is somewhat fuzzy and, as far as I know, not really used mathematically (outside of informal speaking).

Answer (score 0):

I would use computer science and the concept of classes and objects. Let **Shape** be a **class**, say:

> class Shape(shape) [Array pts];

Then define **Circle** as a **subclass** of Shape:

> class Circle of Shape [pts={center,radius}];

Then your circle is an **object**:

> myCircle = new Circle({0,0},15);

**Links**

[Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_%28computer_science%29)

[Class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28computer_programming%29)

Comment: "Instance" may be better than "object" as the upshot of your analogy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885385/what-is-the-difference-between-an-instance-and-an-object; @Blue;

Comment: I like this quote from one of the answers in that link: *"Objects are the definitions of something, instances are the physical things."* Insofar as a circle is "a thing with radius and center", it's a "definitional" *object*; but once I've specified that radius and center, it's a "physical" *instance*. The latter situation seems to be what the OP wants to describe. In any case, something like "the Unit Circle is the particular instance of a circle that has its center at the origin and radius of length one" is natural-sounding English; "object" doesn't seem to lend itself to such natural prose.

Comment: @Blue; but 'instance-oriented programming' doesn't ring the same bells.

Comment: @blue, if i add a draw() function, is the object the abstract circle and the instance the graphic circle?

Comment: I haven't the time, and this isn't the place, for protracted debate. I'll just add this response to your "graphic circle" question: [Ceci n'est pas une pipe.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Treachery_of_Images) :)

Comment: @Jon Mark Perry Thanks for your answer. I am a programmer by profession, so I'm familiar with these concepts, and in fact I asked this question because I was trying to think of what to name the shape library that I'm writing. Your analogy makes sense, but I was looking for a specific geometrical term.